# PHP move_uploaded_file not uploading

Tags: php

I am using this code in PHP:

```
if($at[is_attachment]==1) {
    $filename = $ticketnumber."-".date("YmdHis").'-'.$at[filename];
    $target_path = '../../../media/ticket_attachments/';
    $target_path = $target_path.$filename; 
    if(move_uploaded_file($at[attachment], $target_path)) {
        echo 'yes';
    }
}
```

but its not moving the file to the location, the script this is run on is located in:

```
admin > autochecks > helpdesk > emails.php
```

and the `media` directory is located outside `admin`

i have tried:

```
move_uploaded_file($at[attachment], $target_path)
```

but this is just showing `bool(false)`

permissions on both `media` and `ticket_attachments` directory are 777

Comment: use copy and unlink function to move and delete. move_uploaded_file is for upload only

Comment: You're trying to move an uploaded file, but elsewhere you say that the file hasn't been uploaded (by POST) - which is it? The code you've posted doesn't make any sense. If you're uploading a file use the example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php, if you're moving a file that's already there use http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php.

Comment: the file is being processed from an email attachment so its not physically being uploaded

Comment: Then you can't use `move_uploaded_file` - that's only for files uploaded by POST. Use the example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php to move a file (the function is called `rename` but it's used for renaming files).

Comment: how can i rename a file that hasn;t been saved. anyway, move_uploaded_file will work fine as it has in the past

Comment: *"its not a post request –  charlie 1 hour ago"* - what do you mean by that? If your form doesn't use a POST method, that will explain it. Handling files uses POST and nothing else. Why not post your HTML form and leave the guesswork out? ;-) you'll also need to show more PHP, since we don't know how `$at` is being populated from. In the meantime, use error reporting. I won't be keeping this tab open, so @ me if you need me.

Comment: Where is your file if it hasn't been saved (and hasn't been POSTed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move code should be

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"], $target_path))
```

[PHP 5 File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: its not a post request

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$target_path = '../../../media/ticket_attachments/';
```

To:

```
$target_path = './../../../media/ticket_attachments/';
```

Comment: Check the error log inside helpdesk to trace where an error is. If there's none, remove the if and just call "move_uploaded_file($at[attachment], $target_path)"

Answer (score 0):

move_uploded function is used to move the file which is uploded from the request and is in temp.

TRY THIS -

```
if($at[is_attachment]==1) {
    $filename = $ticketnumber."-".date("YmdHis").'-'.$at[filename];
    $target_path = '../../../media/ticket_attachments/';
    $target_path = $target_path.$filename; 
    if(copy($at[attachment], $target_path)==1 ) {
        if(unlink($at[attachment])){
        echo 'yes';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its not getting past the if(copy($at[attachment], $target_path)==1 ) { line

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this path:

```
    $target_path = '../../../media/ticket_attachments/';
```

With this :

```
    $target_path = '../../media/ticket_attachments/';
```